# How do I include a 5-pixel colored gap around each edge of each image in processing?

Tags: image-processing, processing

I am trying to my school project now, and we're asked to make 5-pixel colored gap around each edge of each images.

I tried to use the `line ()`, `stroke ()` and `strokeWeight ()` function but it doesn't make it. I think maybe the lines shows under the image, maybe I should make the lines overlapping the images? Is there any other way that I can make it?

This is what I've done so far

```
PImage cat;
PImage cat2;
PImage cat3;
PImage cat4;
PImage cat5;
PImage cat6;
PImage cat7;
PImage cat8;

color Purple = color(186,85,211);

void setup() {
    // load the image file from the "data" folder
    cat = loadImage("cat.jpg");

    // showing the same 9 images, perfectly arranged as 3-by-3 grid
    size(cat.width + cat.width + cat.width,
      (cat.height + cat.height + cat.height));
}

void draw() {
    //  Gap
    line (0, 0, width*3, 0);
    line (0, height*2, width*3, height*2);
    stroke (186,85,211);
    strokeWeight (5);

    // The background is purple
    background (Purple);

    // purple tint
    tint(186,85,211,126);
    // The image fllows the mouse pointer 
    image(cat, mouseX, mouseY);

    // make a copy of the original
    cat2 = cat.get();
    // No Tint
    tint(255, 255);
    // apply the black & white filter
    cat2.filter (THRESHOLD, 0.7);
    //display the image
    image(cat2, cat2.width, 0);

    // make a copy of the orginal
    cat3 = cat.get();
    // apply the grayscale filter
    cat3.filter(GRAY);
    //display the image
    image(cat3, cat.width*2, 0);

    // make a copy of the original
    cat4 = cat.get();
    // apply the INVERT filter 
    cat4.filter(INVERT);
    //display the image
    image(cat4, 0, cat.height); 

    // original
    image(cat, cat.width*1, cat.height*1);

    // make a copy of the original
    cat5 = cat.get();
    // apply the Posterize filter
    cat5.filter(POSTERIZE,4);
    //display the image
    image(cat5, cat.width*2, cat.height*1);

    // make a copy of the original
    cat6 = cat.get();
    // apply the Blur filter 
    cat6.filter(BLUR,5);
    //display the image
    image(cat6, 0, cat.height*2);

    // make a copy the original
    cat7 = cat.get();
    // make the Eroded filter
    cat7.filter(ERODE);
    //display the image
    image(cat7, cat.width, cat.height*2);

    // make a copy of the original
    cat8 = cat.get();
    // apply the DILATE filter
    cat8.filter(DILATE);
    //display the image
    image(cat8, cat.width*2, cat.height*2);
}
```

Desired outcome:

[image]

The actual outcome is like:
[image]

Comment: could you add an image to illustrate your question?

Comment: Sorry I can't add an image here because it needs at lease 10 reputation to upload the image, so I tried to upload the image here: 
http://postimg.org/image/sd4nogufx/

Comment: The cats are in the same image, or there are 9 images? you could add what you have tried so far (the code),  and the outcome of your code (another screenshot).

Comment: this is what I've done so far 

http://textuploader.com/60pb

and the outcome is like:

 http://postimg.org/image/3t9hochcd/

The cats are in the same image, I just duplicate the original one and play around with the filter functions.

Comment: Looks like you are drawing the lines first, then the images, the images would cover the lines. Try do it in reverse order, first images, then lines

Comment: Just like @Mike's answer, your desired outcome can be achieved by applying 5 pixels of padding between the images, by using the correct coordinates you don't have to draw the purple lines at all. You can try his code and accept his answer if that works.

Answer (score 1):

Don't think in terms of construction, think in terms of result: what you're showing is *also* simply a pinkish `background()` with the images spaced based on several pixels padding:

```
ArrayList<PImage> cats = new ArrayList<Pimage>();

...

void draw() {
  background(155,0,155);
  int padding = 5,
      w = width - 4*padding,
      h = height - 4*padding;
  for (int row=0; row<4; row++) {
    for (int col=0; col<4; col++) {
      int idx = row * 3 + col;
      image(cats.get(idx), col*(w+padding), row*(h+padding), w, h);
    }
  }
}
```